# How to rearrange report which is displayed on the cylinder tracking page of reportico

Tags: reportico

"On the Cylinder Tracking page of reportico, I've noticed that the list of reports appears in a random order, which is not convenient for efficient navigation. I would like to reorganize these reports alphabetically to make it easier to locate specific information. Can you guide me on how to achieve this sorting arrangement on the page?"